# How to implement lossy buffering?

Tags: fifo, buffer

I want to capture log data and analyze it in real time. Specifically the output of mysql's slow query log. However this needs to be minimally invasive.

Pointing the source to a FIFO rather than a conventional file eliminates the need for handling file rotation removal and its associated complexities but does pose the risk of blocking if the data is not read quickly enough. The DBMS will be generating output at a high rate and I would rather lose data in the pipe than slow down/block the writing side.

Is this achievable?

I did consider using UDPcast as a sender/receiver however it appears it still enforces integrity management on the data stream.